# Declaring multiple empty variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object

I tried doing this:

```
var1, var2, var3 = {}
```

and only the last var was an object, is i posible to create multiple empty objects or arrays without doing

```
var all = {}, used = {}, unused = {};
```

?

Comment: nope. weeell, it's more complicated than `var var1={}, var2={}` anyway...

Comment: Why you really need that? You have written the correct method and asking us for an answer!

Comment: The short answer is _no_ , what you're doing (in the second method) is the correct way to do this. If your variables are sequential (like var1 var2 var3...) you should use an array but from your second code snippet that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is similar to :

```
var1;
var2;
var3 = {};
```

What you need is :

```
var1 = var2 = var3 = {};
```

Comment: -1; only 1 object with 3 variables referencing to it will be created. and my eyes bleed from use of global variables.

Comment: @Pavel - These are not 3 different objects. They are one. Making change in either of these references will reflect in all of them.